# setInterval data received closes opened subItems

Tags: angular, setinterval

I have an *ngFor list of mainItems, each of which has an *ngFor list of subItems.  When I load the list of mainItems and press the 'plus' icon on mainItem it opens a list of subItems.

The open/close functionality is obtained by the following code:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign " title="sub items" (click)="item.hideme = !item.hideme"></span>
```

Each mainItem creates it's own property item.hideme and toggles it between true/false.

I use a setInterval function to load content of mainItems and subItems from a file and put it in a content Array every 1 second. The **PROBLEM** is that every time setInterval updates this.contentArray and closes all the subItems because the new contentArray does not have the item.hideme property on initialization.

How can I load new data and maintain the toggle state of subItems that have already been opened?

TypeScript class I am using to accomplish the intended functionality:

```js
  @Component({
        providers: [StructureRequestService],
        styleUrls: ['app/home/home.css'],
        templateUrl:'./app/home/homePageTemplate.html'
        // directives: [ AttachmentComponent ]
  })
  export class HomeComponent {
        contentArray = [];
        myRes: Content;
        showAssigned:boolean = false;
        showSubitems:boolean = false;
        showUsers:boolean = false;

        constructor(private structureRequest: StructureRequestService) {
              setInterval(() => {
                    this.timerGetStructure();
              }, 1500);
        }
        //using with setInterval to get new data and sets into content Array with this.updateItems(result)
        timerGetStructure() {
              this.structureRequest.sendRequest().subscribe((result) => this.updateItems(result));
        }

        updateItems(result) {
              this.myRes =  result;
              this.contentArray = this.myRes.content;
        }

        ngOnInit() {
              //makes http request and puts result into contantArray
              this.structureRequest.sendRequest().subscribe((result) => this.viewNodes(result));
        }

        //view items
        viewNodes(result) {
              //console.log(result);
              this.myRes =  result;
              this.contentArray = this.myRes.content;
              this.showAssigned = true;
        }
  }
```

homePageTemplate.html:

```js
<div class="row"  *ngFor="let item of contentArray">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign " title="sub items" (click)="item.hideme = !item.hideme"></span>
    <div class=" itemName" title="State:{{item.state}},Type: {{item.type}}">{{item.name}}</div>

   <div class="row" *ngIf="item.hideme">
        <div class="row" *ngFor="let child of item.children">
           <div class="  itemName" title="State:{{child.state}}>{{child.name}} </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to bind `*ngIf` to a different property where `item.hideme` is not overridden by `setInterval()`

Comment: I've created separated property in component, and now it does not closes subItems. But when I press show/hide button it open/close subItems on all mainItems. How to make separated property for each *ngFor item??

Comment: Can you please provide a Plunker that allows to reproduce. It's difficult to debug a program that is only partially available and it's only described in prose how the used data looks like.